# Error when reading ClickHouse table with complex data types using PySpark JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, clickhouse

I am trying to read data from a ClickHouse table using PySpark's JDBC connector. The table schema includes complex data types such as Tuple and Array.

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE test.test
(
    `TupleTypeExample` Tuple(left Nullable(Float64),top Nullable(Float64)),
    `ArrayTypeExample` Array(Nullable(Int8)),
    `EnumTypeExample` Nullable(Enum8('cat' = 1, 'dog' = 2)),
    `serverTime` DateTime
)
```

When I read the data using a `options.query("")` and perform type casting, it works fine and I get the expected results.

```
query_string_formated = "SELECT CAST(TupleTypeExample AS String) AS TupleTypeExampleString, CAST(ArrayTypeExample AS String) AS ArrayTypeExampleString, CAST(EnumTypeExample AS integer) AS EnumTypeExampleinteger FROM test.test"
pgDF=spark.read.format('jdbc')\
    .option('driver',driver)\
    .option('url',url)\
    .option('user',user)\
    .option('password',password)\
    .option('query',query_string_formated)\
    .load()
```

However, when I try to read the data without specifying a query and provide a custom schema, I encounter the following **error**:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o248.load.
: com.github.housepower.exception.ClickHouseSQLException: Unknown data type: left
```

**Code:**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ClickHouse Example") \
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077")\
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/opt/spark/jars/clickhouse-native-jdbc-shaded-2.6.5.jar")\
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/opt/spark/jars/clickhouse-native-jdbc-shaded-2.6.5.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

driver="com.github.housepower.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver"
custom_schema = StructType([
    StructField("TupleTypeExample", StructType([
        StructField("left", DoubleType(), nullable=True),
        StructField("top", DoubleType(), nullable=True)
    ])),
    StructField("ArrayTypeExample", ArrayType(IntegerType(), containsNull=True), nullable=True),
    StructField("EnumTypeExample", StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("serverTime", TimestampType(), nullable=True)
])

pgDF_a = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
    .option('driver', driver) \
    .option('url', url) \
    .option('user', user) \
    .option('password', password) \
    .option('dbtable', dbtable) \
    .schema(custom_schema) \
    .load()

print(pgDF_a.show())
```

I would like to understand why I am getting this error when using the custom schema and how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.